# How to add a new list in SharePoint 2013 using Rest service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, postman

This is my URL to create new list in share point.

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists
```

Headers

```
Accept:application/json
odata:verbose
X-RequestDigest:0x95F99ED44821F59DE52F628A82E4DFE6281D64349398251D47B063BEA15AA783C70656A30E0EC388C62E72E001B4F2BEB7AD716DAF1F63D79A170A8A4C299182,03 May 2016 07:01:30 -0000
content-type:application/json;
odata=verbose
content-length:6
```

Body

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.List"
        },
        "AllowContentTypes": true,
        "BaseTemplate"  :  100,
        "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
        "Description": "My ow list created",
        "Title": "newList"

    }
}
```

But When try to execute this URL in Postman am getting following error

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Can someone guide me why am facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for this error is that your form digest has been expired.

Try with making a new form digest by making a POST request to **/_api/contextinfo** endpoint and then replace it in your **Header** section.

I've tested your code with the following **Body** and it is working.

```
    {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.List"
        },
        "AllowContentTypes": true,
        "BaseTemplate"  :  100,
        "ContentTypesEnabled": true,
        "Description": "My own list created",
        "Title": "newList"
     }
```